# how to display the response on main UI from a socket IO in fragmentactivity in AndroidStudio, from a Node JS server?

Tags: android, google-maps, sockets

//how to read the data from emitter listener in an activity and in a //fragmentActivity and in a fragment, i can read data in Log but not on the same //UI.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://6d34f177.ngrok.io");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.e("oSocket", "onCreate: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    mSocket.connect();




    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


}

private Emitter.Listener Z = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];

                try {
                    message = data.getString("msg");
                    time
```

= data.getString("time");

```
                    Log.e("Resp", time);
                    Log.e("Respo", message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return;
                }
```

// here i can  get the response from server and can get printed on Log but not able to set it on textview.?
                    tv.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }
    };

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.hp.zz/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.hp.zz/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly happens when you use `tv.setText()`?

Comment: Hello Naveen, when i set a tv.setText inside a background thread of ( emitter.listener event)  I am getting a null value.  also one strange case hapenning if i am opning the exact same app in two different devices, i am getting tv.setText value correctly , but clicking from device first , and getting displayed on second device and vice versa. Please Reply... Please.

Comment: Can any good Coder help me, solving my problem  ?

Comment: I don't know what kind of null you are getting. If its a 'Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference' then your `TextView` wasn't found. Try setting tv as a volatile variable.

Comment: actually it is a background thread. ust tell me how and which process will be best  to use  for making a dealy, handler or async task...and what is the best practice to do it...

Comment: For delay handler would be your best option. I don't really know of any best practices for it though.

Comment: Hello Everyone, finally i have found the answer of my 50 day long problem. It  (strange case hapenning if i am opning the exact same app in two different devices, i am getting tv.setText value correctly , but clicking from device first , and getting displayed on second device and vice versa. ) was happening because of my Server side Coding of NodeJS. I was using socket.broadcast.emit which was sending the messages to all the other clients except the newly created connection. The correct library was, to use  : io.sockets.emit  which could have send data to all the clients ...